# Display an account as "subheader" in select statement?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

My manager asked me to change up how our cost report is displayed. She wants the data to end up looking like this:

```
Account | Transaction_date | Short Description
123456  |  (null)          | (null)
 (null) | 10-31-2013       | Waste of time
 (null) | 10-31-2013       | Happy Halloween
```

This is how the table usually displays data:

```
Account | Transaction_date | Short Description
 123456 | 10-31-2013       | Waste of time
 123456 | 10-31-2013       | Happy Halloween
```

Now I thought the `lag` function might help me here or some sort of `loop` but each time before I finished I realized data would be missing or would be displayed incorrectly. I tried looking via Google if anyone else had to do this sort of thing but came up empty handed. I guess my question is, is this even possible or can I move on to more important things?

Comment: Could you give us some example data from the original table

Comment: Added it to the original question.

Comment: You're looking to create a group header. It would be much easier to do that in most reporting tools than in a SQL query. Do you have some sort of intervening tools between the raw SQL results and the consumers of your report?

Comment: The data usually gets exported to Excel. I knew I could do it manually there but that in my opinion is too time consuming if I need to do it multiple times a week.

Comment: you might consider eventually moving to an actual reporting software like Crystal or Actuate or similar (its been a while for me, probably some freeware options also).  But gives you a ton more formatting functionality

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way is to do it on the CLIENT site not in the SQL statement.

Also you can do it in SQL

[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/640dd/9)

```
select Account,
       Transaction_date,
       Short_Description

FROM
(
select distinct 0 Ord , Account OrdAcc,
                  Account, 
                  NULL Transaction_date,
                  NULL Short_Description
FROM T
UNION ALL
select 1 Ord , Account OrdAcc,
                  NULL Account, 
                  Transaction_date,
                  Short_Description
FROM T

) T1

ORDER BY OrdAcc,Ord
```

Comment: Holly crap, this is very nice. Thank you for bringing this to my attention.